# Vertical Seekbar - horizontal circle

Tags: android, seekbar

i'm trying to create Vertical Seekbar. My problem is on image:

[http://postimg.org/image/8xn6qkgn1/ http://s30.postimg.org/j7plpt6io/Screenshot_2015_05_24_14_37_38.jpg](http://s30.postimg.org/j7plpt6io/Screenshot_2015_05_24_14_37_38.jpg)

The circle is horizontal, but thumb and seek bar are vertical.

VerticalSeekbar code:

```
public class VerticalSeekBar extends SeekBar {

    public VerticalSeekBar(Context context){
        super(context);
    }

    public VerticalSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public VerticalSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh){
        super.onSizeChanged(h, w, oldh, oldw);
    }

    @Override
    protected synchronized void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
        super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas c){
        c.rotate(90);
        c.translate(0, - getWidth());
        super.onDraw(c);
    }

    private OnSeekBarChangeListener onSeekBarChangeListener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser){

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar){

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar){

        }
    };

    @Override
    public void setOnSeekBarChangeListener(OnSeekBarChangeListener onSeekBarChangeListener){
        this.onSeekBarChangeListener = onSeekBarChangeListener;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (!isEnabled()) {
            return false;
        }

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                onSeekBarChangeListener.onStartTrackingTouch(this);
                setPressed(true);
                setSelected(true);
                applyProgress(event);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                super.onTouchEvent(event);
                setPressed(true);
                setSelected(true);
                applyProgress(event);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                onSeekBarChangeListener.onStopTrackingTouch(this);
                setPressed(false);
                setSelected(false);
                applyProgress(event);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                super.onTouchEvent(event);
                setPressed(false);
                setSelected(false);
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void applyProgress(MotionEvent event){
        int progress = (int) (getMax() * event.getY() / getHeight()) - 0;
        setProgress((int) (getMax() * event.getY() / getHeight()) - 0);
        onSizeChanged(getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Thanks for help!